# Select timer continues running after the process has been stopped with SIGSTOP?

Tags: linux, select, signals

I have tried to stop a process through sending `SIGSTOP` and then after the timeout value of select `(4min)` then send a `SIGCONT`. The select call immediately then fails with a `timeout`, is there a way to prevent having select's timer running while the process is frozen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select seems to check the OS time and based on it decides if the timeout has been elapsed. So even if the process is suspended, Select will still timeout (if the process was suspended during a select call of course)